# Mac show/delete custom URL schemes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, url-scheme

I have made an cocoa mac application which can be called by a URL-Scheme. After a while I was unsatisfied by the current URL-scheme name and changed it. But my mac still reacts on the old URL-scheme.

Is there a way to list and even delete (custom) URL-schemes?

Ps. If I release a new version of the application, I am not certain that the URL-scheme is overridden by the new application, can some one confirm this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was Googling for a solution to this, saw your post, then was able to solve the problem.

Close all applications and

Open terminal and dump this into it:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

That should do it for you. Worked for me. This will Rebuild LaunchServices to Remove Duplicates for you.

Comment: Thank you. I recently found a quick solution: When the application starts search for the application in the 'activity monitor' and inspect it. Then look for the location of the application and delete in manually.